# Switching apps based on where user looks

Tags: macos, applications, display

I am using MBP with external monitor, in addition to the build-in display. It happens quite often that I 'mentally' switch to other monitor, but the active application is still on different one, where I don't look. Then I start typing, or press some shortcut which leads to unwanted behaviour (e.g. I close an editor tab instead of tab in the chrome).

I was wondering is there is any app, which would use camera to guess where the user is looking and switch the active app accordingly. I am sure that it would not be perfect, but I would give it a try.

Any other suggestions to deal with my problem are also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

My answer falls in the "other suggestions" opening provided.

There's a tool called **[Isolator](http://willmore.eu/software/isolator/)** that may help you stop mistaking which app is in the foreground (and keep your focus in the right place).  Here's the description from the tool's home page:

> Isolator is a small menu bar application that helps you concentrate.
>   When you're working on a document, and don't want to be distracted,
>   turn on Isolator. It will cover up your desktop and all the icons on
>   it, as well as the windows of all your other applications, so you can
>   concentrate on the task in hand.

There's an option to make background windows **blurry** or **semi-transparent**, in lieu of simply hiding them.  Witness the blur:

[image: Screenshot showing Isolator blur effect]
([source](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/06/focus-apps-and-apply-background-filters-isolator-mac-os-x/))

Reviews elsewhere:

- [OS X Daily: Focus on Apps Easier & Apply Background Filters with Isolator for Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/06/focus-apps-and-apply-background-filters-isolator-mac-os-x/)
- [Lifehacker: Download of the Day: Isolator (Mac)](http://lifehacker.com/239746/download-of-the-day-isolator-mac) – mentions two similar tools.
- [MacApper: Anti-Distraction Apps: Keep Yourself On Task](http://macapper.com/2007/02/21/anti-distraction-apps-keep-yourself-on-task/) – (ditto)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I am giving it thumb up. But it's not really a solution for me, since I am actually using both monitors at the same time (e.g. source code on first and doc on second), so hiding one would basically be like switching to single screen.